# Month name order by in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Dear friends I need help,

This is my query,

```
$customer = DB::table('customer');
$customer->join('customer_month_calender', 
   'customer_month_calender.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id','left');

$customer->select('customer.id','customer_month_calender.month');
//$customer->where(DATE_FORMAT(month,'%m')=date('m',strtotime('+1 month')));
$customer->orderBy('customer_month_calender.month', 'create_date');
$customer->groupBy('customer.id');

return $customer->get();
```

This query return values for,

```
April  
August  
December  
February  
January  
July  
June
```

However, I wanted to have the Month names in order by

(ie. January, February, Mar.. an so on until the last one is December).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an array return form the $customer->get(); ?

Comment: yes it is an array

Comment: `ORDER BY Field(customer_month_calender, "January", "February", "Mar" an so on until the last one is "December")`

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this using `orderBy` with `raw` query:

```
$customer = DB::table('customer');
$customer->join('customer_month_calender', 
   'customer_month_calender.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id','left');

$customer->select('customer.id','customer_month_calender.month');
//$customer->where(DATE_FORMAT(month,'%m')=date('m',strtotime('+1 month')));
$customer->orderBy(DB::raw('month(create_date) ASC'));
$customer->groupBy('customer.id');

return $customer->get();
```

Comment: Unknown column 'create_date' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `customer`.`id`, `customer_month_calender`.`month` from `customer` left join `customer_month_calender` on `customer_month_calender`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id` group by `customer`.`id` order by month(create_date) asc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) mysqli class, You could try with

```
$customer->orderBy('MONTH(create_date)', 'ASC');
```

With raw query:

```
ORDER BY MONTH(create_date)
```

Of course, you can customize to match your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
    $customer = DB::table('customer');
$customer->join('customer_month_calender', 
   'customer_month_calender.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id','left');

$customer->select('customer.id','customer_month_calender.month');
//$customer->where(DATE_FORMAT(month,'%m')=date('m',strtotime('+1 month')));
$customer->orderBy('customer_month_calender.month ASC');
$customer->groupBy('customer.id');

return $customer->get();
```